# phpmyadmin - Error when connecting to localhost/phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost, ubuntu-18.04

After installing xampp 7.3 version in ubuntu I tried running xampp and the mysql database appeared to stop so I executed these commands:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp status

sudo service mysql stop
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

After executing that, `mysql` was in running state. So then I entered: 
`localhost/phpmyadmin` in url box and got the following error

[image: (screenshot)]

Let me know how could this error be eliminated.

Aditional info requested in the comments:

```
$ ls -ld /opt/lampp/temp
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody daemon 4096, 
$ pgrep lampp | xargs ps -o pid
3485
$ pgrep lampp | xargs ps -o user
daemon
$ pgrep lampp | xargs ps -o cmd
/opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL - –
```

Comment: The error indicates that PHPMyAdmin can not read and write in the directory `/opt/lampp/temp`. Please check which user `lampp` is running under and what the permissions on that directory are. You can use the commands `ls -ld /opt/lampp/temp` and `pgrep lampp | xargs ps -o pid,user,cmd` for that.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. As i am beginner some of these arent making sense to me so these are the outputs i received when entering the commands you mentioned. 
ls -ld /opt/lampp/temp : drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody daemon 4096, 
pgrep lampp | xargs ps -o pid : 3485, 
pgrep lampp | xargs ps -o user : daemon, 
pgrep lampp | xargs ps -o cmd : /opt/lampp/bin/httpd -k start -E /opt/lampp/logs/error_log -DSSL -

Comment: Can you please post the output of the commands as an edit at the bottom of your original post. And please put them inside a code block. They are hardly readable in the comment.

Comment: Sure @Lucas I have done it now here